# How to scaling big image smoothly in canvas with drawImage?

Tags: html, canvas

When I use drawImage to scalle a big image (like 5M), the result looks terrible， is there any easier way that can scalling image with anti-aliasing? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) has mentioned about this:

Note: Images can become blurry when scaling up or grainy if they're scaled down too much. Scaling is probably best not done if you've got some text in it which needs to remain legible.

**EIDT:** I wanna scale a image to 90x90, and my code is like this:

```
that.avatar_height >= that.avatar_width ?
that.context.drawImage($(this)[0], 86, 2, 90, that.avatar_height*90/that.avatar_width) :
that.context.drawImage($(this)[0], 86, 2, that.avatar_width*90/that.avatar_height, 90);
```

avatar is the image to be scaled.

Answer (score 1):

While scaling the image first get the uploaded image aspect ratio.

```
/* Calculating aspect ratio */
var imageAspectRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight;

/* Give the needed width and height of the image*/
/*For example you need like this */
var newWidth = 1024;
var newHeight = 768;

if( imgWidth <= 1024 ) {
    var newWidth =  newHeight * imageAspectRatio;
} else if(imgHeight <= 768) {
    var newHeight = newWidth / imageAspectRatio;
} else if( imgWidth >= newWidth ) {
    var newWidth =  newHeight * imageAspectRatio;
} else if(imgHeight >= newHeight) {
    var newHeight = newWidth / imageAspectRatio;
}
```

If you do this you can't loss you aspect ratio so scaling looks good

Comment: Thank you, but see my edit, my way is same as you have just provided, it doesn't works:(